# How do I select a range of cells in without giving the range a name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to select cells C29:Z50 as a variable using apps script. I'd prefer not to have to create a named range (but I can if needed).

My goal is to create some custom formatting beyond colors that can use built in functionality. So, if cell B27 = "Transactions" then format C29:Z50 as a number, else format Z29:Z50 as dollar currency.

So I don't need the values of the cells, just the group of cells as a variable that I can apply if logic to.

I was reading the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getDataRange()).

> getDataRange()
>
> Returns a Range corresponding to the dimensions in which data is
>   present. This is functionally equivalent to creating a Range bounded
>   by A1 and (Range.getLastColumn(), Range.getLastRow()).

The example in the documentation grabs the entire tab but I just want a subset of the sheet in question.

I tried:

```
var currency_range = ss.getDataRange(C29, Z50); //"Reference Error. "C29" is not defined."

var currency_range = ss.getDataRange(C29:Z50); // "Missing ) argument list"
```

How can I "get" the range of cells so that I can later edit their formatting based on if conditional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Spreadsheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRange(String)). For example, this should work:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("...");
var currencyRange = ss.getRange("C29:Z250");
```

Well, actually I'm using this [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)) method instead, but they should be the same in your case. It offers more ways to declare the desired range, such as `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`, which could be useful for you too.

Comment: As for how to check if you got it right... you could log [the values in the range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) (for example, the first and the last cells), or [change the background color](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackground(String)), or anything similar. Just use any method you want from the [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) class instead of logging directly the object.