# How do I get Google Script to hide rows with blanks or zeroes in a specific column, within a specific range of rows?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements

I'm new to coding, and this is my first question on stackoverflow.

I want to hide every row within a range of rows that has a blank or zero in a specific column, in this case, column D.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Invoice Template');
        s.getRange('d:d')
```

It is hiding every row with a zero in it in the whole column, but I want it to hid only zeroes between rows 13 and 29.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select a range of cells in without giving the range a name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352246/how-do-i-select-a-range-of-cells-in-without-giving-the-range-a-name)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. When including code in a question usually the best is that his code be a [mcve]. Also it's a good idea to include a brief description of your search/research efforts regarding what is being asked.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I found a work around as the logic that has been suggested to fix the problem by @The Brenny is sound, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
     .getSheetByName('Invoice Template');

s.getRange('d13:d29') // Here's the fix!
     .getValues()
     .forEach(function (r, i) {
        if (r[0] !== '' && r[0].toString()
            .charAt(0) == 0) s.hideRows(i + 1)
    });
```

You're selecting the whole column in your code using `s.getRange('d:d')`. This should actually be `s.getRange('d13:d29')` to specify that you only want to process data between rows 13 and 29.

Comment: Hi @TheBrenny, thank you. I tried that but it doesn't work. I have found a work around.

Comment: I added spaces in column D so that those rows wouldn't be hidden. Clunky, but effective.